# unable to update app service stack after updating version

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I have a webapp which is running in Node 16, I am updating to node 18. I have used below command to update.

```
az webapp config set -g RG_NAME -n APP_NAME --linux-fx-version "NODE|18LTS
```

once done, when I run `az webapp config show`, I can see its in Node 18, but the UI (Azure portal) doesnt show the latest changes, because the stack is choosen Empty. when I manually set the stack to Node, its showing properly. Is it just UI issue or I have to set any parameters to actually update the stack ?

Comment: How are you deploying the WebApp? From `VSCode` or `Visual Studio`?

Comment: thorugh Devops pipeiline

Answer (score 0):

I have created `NodeJS App`  and deployed to `Azure Linux App Service` with `NODE 16LTS`.

- Immediately after deploying the app, in `Azure Portal`  I can see the stack as `NODE 16`.
- As you have mentioned, updated the runtime stack with `NODE 18 LTS` with the given command.

```js
az webapp config set -g YourRGName -n YourAppName --linux-fx-version "NODE|18LTS"
```

- Even I can see the runtime stack setting becoming empty.

[image]

> Is it just UI issue or I have to set any parameters to actually update the stack ?

- AFAIK, we don't have any option to set the parameters while updating the stack.
- Manually I have updated the runtime stack and again tried to update the version for the second time with CLI Command.
- Again, I see the runtime stack option Empty. This is the default behavior of `Azure App Service UI` in Portal.